# React view not updating on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I have a list of names to render. The list is filtered by a search input, but also by a gender_id.

The problem is, when I update the saved_id of an object in my array, the view does not change. My child component has a button that outputs 'Save' if saved_id is 1, and 'Remove' if saved_id is 2. I can console.log both the 'names'- and 'searchFilteredNames'-arrays after updating the state, and both get the update. But the const'genderFilteredNames' that i use .map() on to render the list, does not catch the change for some reason... Any ideas why that could be?

Parent component (table with names):

```
export default function Names(props) {
/* Raw list */
const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

/* Search filtered list */
const [searchFilteredNames, setSearchFilteredNames] = useState([...names]);

/* Gender filter */
const [genderFilter, setGenderFilter] = useState(1);

/* Show only names where gender_id is equal to gender filter AND status === 1 */
const genderFilteredNames = searchFilteredNames.filter((name) => {
  return name.status_id === 1 && name.gender_id === genderFilter;
});

/* Get names from Database on render */
useEffect(() => {
  getNames();
}, []);

/* Update search-filtered array on root array update */
useEffect(() => {
  setSearchFilteredNames(names);
}, [names]);

/* Get names */
function getNames() {
  axios.get("http://localhost:3001/select").then((response) => {
    setNames(response.data);
  });
}

/* Update object in array */
function updateSave(id, savedId) {
  // Make copy of original array
  let newNames = [...names];

  // Get index of object to update
  for (var index = 0; index < names.length; index++) if (names[index].id === id) break;

  // Update object value
  newNames[index].saved_id = savedId;

  // Set the state to new copy
  setNames(newNames)
}

/* Render names */
function renderNames() {
  return genderFilteredNames.map((name) => (
    <Name
      key={name.id}
      id={name.id}
      name={name.name}
      saved={name.saved_id}
      gender_id={name.gender_id}
      use={() => handleUse(name.id)}
      save={() => handleSave(name.id)}
    />
  ));
}
...
```

Child component (single row):

```
export default function Name(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState(props.name);
  const [saved, setSaved] = useState(props.saved);
  const useFn = props.use;
  const saveFn = props.save;

  function savedStatus() {
    return saved === 1 ? <>Save</> : <>Remove</>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <tr>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td className="actions-2">
          <button className="btn btn-tan" onClick={useFn}>
            <FaRegEdit />
            Use
          </button>

          <button className="btn btn-tan" onClick={saveFn}>
            <GiSaveArrow />
            {savedStatus()}
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized why it wasnt working.... I was using useState for saved_status in child component, and not updating it with setState...

here:

```
export default function Name(props) {
const [name, setName] = useState(props.name); 
const [saved, setSaved] = useState(props.saved);***** HERE ******
```

changed to:

```
export default function Name(props) {
const name = props.name;
const saved = props.saved;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're directly mutating a state object, which you must not do with React state. Here's where:

```
function updateSave(id, savedId) {
  // Make copy of original array
  let newNames = [...names];

  // Get index of object to update
  for (var index = 0; index < names.length; index++) if (names[index].id === id) break;

  // Update object value
  newNames[index].saved_id = savedId; // <========================== *** here

  // Set the state to new copy
  setNames(newNames)
}
```

Instead, you have to set a *new* object in that element of the new array you've created:

```
function updateSave(id, savedId) {
  // Make copy of original array
  let newNames = [...names];

  // Get index of object to update
  for (var index = 0; index < names.length; index++) if (names[index].id === id) break;

  // Update object value
  newNames[index].saved_id = {...newNames[index], saved_id = savedId}; // *** here

  // Set the state to new copy
  setNames(newNames)
}
```

Now React will see that the object isn't the same as the previous one, and re-render it.

---

Just for what it's worth, I'd probably write that function differently:

```
function updateSave(id, savedId) {
    const newNames = names.map(name => {
        if (name.id === id) {
            // This is the one we're updating, update it
            return {...name, saved_id = saveId};
        }
        return name; // No change
    })
    setNames(newNames);
}
```

Or if you go in for hyper-conciseness (I don't, really; I prefer ease of debugging and leave minifying to minifiers, although this particular idiom is fairly common in React or other immutable code), then:

```
function updateSave(id, savedId) {
    setNames(names.map(name =>
        name.id === id ? {...name, saved_id: saveId} : name
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and it all makes total sense, but it actually didn't seem to fix the issue ):

Comment: @RasmusAndersen - Ah, okay, there were multiple things wrong. :-) I didn't see the copy-props-to-state part of it. That's almost always not what you want.

Comment: Yep... Your fixes in combination with what I discovered, made the whole thing work though. So thank you very much regardless! :)